# Partition table damaged

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm currently in a terrible situation with my hdd:
I was trying to install an OS side by side with my windows 7 x64 and I used the Paragon Partition Manager feature made for that. It disabled/hid/(damaged?) one of my partitions and now I can no longer access it.
The partition, unfortunately, contains data I need to access urgently and I've got no backup.
To complicate things even further I don't have another PC (I'm writing this msg from my iphone) and all I can rely on is a backtrac 4 disk (wkn't connect to my wifi, gets stuck obtaining IP address) and. Windows 7 x64 disk.
Booting into windows fails with the pc hanging on the starting windows screen. Safe mode won't work either.
Is there anything I can do?

Here's the layout of the disk:
Recovery partition
Win partition
Unallocated space (it's supposed to be my data partition)
Other os partition (don't care about that, the installation of the other OS failed)
Please help me, I'm desperate.

Comment: First, get a nail and a magnet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, sorry for the panicking message.

For those who might be in such an awful situation, if you've got a bootable linux disc you can do as follows:

1. Unhide the main windows partition with fdisk
2. Boot windows (booting will work, at this point)
3. Use Paragon Partition Manager to recover partitions
4. Assign a drive letter to the partition, once found

Comment: That was fast...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `gparted` under Linux to scan for filesystems and reconstitute a partition table.  I keep a [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/) USB key around for emergency recovery such as this.